# How do I "install the PHP client by running the command in the plugin root directory"?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, github

I customize Wordpress sites, so I'm somewhat technical but I'm trying to install a plugin from GitHub and the instructions are confusing me.

Here are the Installing instructions:

1. Clone or copy project folder into wp-content/plugins directory

**2. Install the SpinPapi PHP client by running the commands git submodule init and git submodule update in the WPSpin root directory

3. Ensure that the WPSpin/spinpapi/tmp folder is writable by the web server user**

4. Activate plugin from WordPress plugins screen

I'm pretty baffled by numbers 2 and 3. How do I run a command in a root directory? And when I downloaded the zip file, there isn't even a WPSpin/spinpapi/tmp folder, so how do I make it writable?

This is the page I'm looking at: [Github reference link](https://github.com/emumarketing/WPSpin)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you connect to your server by ssh?

if yes, you can execute command like:

connect to your server

```
ssh username@mydomain.com
```

1: clone git repository

```
git clone https://github.com/emumarketing/WPSpin.git
```

2: Install the SpinPapi PHP client

```
cd WPSpin
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

3: search on google about chmod to make the folder writable

Comment: Ok that helped a ton, I got most of the way there. I connected via ssh and followed your instructions, but I still don't get how to make that folder writable. I can't even see that folder existing, but that's probably because it's not writable? When I try to activate the plugin I get a "fatal error" from the first line of functions.php so I'm guessing its not installed correctly. How do I run a chmod command on a folder that my user can't even see?

Comment: The Wordpress system was breaking on the first line of the plugin's functions.php file. Either way I ended up going with a different solution. Thanks for the help, I'll close the question!